# Implementing a non-member IO operator

Tags: c++, c++11, input, file-io

In my assignment I was asked to create the Product class, and I have finished all the implementations except the "non-member IO operator". The question I found it very vague, it asks me to overload the `<<` and `>>` operators to work with ostream and istream to read a Product from and print a Product to the console in order to make this main function work.

Here I see the main function has cout or cin to Product's derived class SItem, I wonder how I should implement the `<<` `>>` operators to make the main work.

My main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Product.h"
#include <fstream>
#ifdef TAB
# undef TAB
#endif
#define TAB '\t'
using namespace std;
namespace sict {
    class SItem :public Product {
    public:
        SItem(const char* theSku, const char * theName) :Product(theSku, theName) {}
        SItem() {}
        virtual std::fstream& store(std::fstream& file, bool addNewLine = true)const {
            if (!isEmpty()) {
                file.open("ms4.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
                file << sku() << TAB << name() << TAB << quantity() << TAB << qtyNeeded() << TAB
                    << int(taxed()) << TAB << price() << endl;
                file.clear();
                file.close();
            }
            return file;
        }
        virtual std::fstream& load(std::fstream& file) {
            file.open("ms4.txt", ios::in);
            char buf[2000];
            double dbuf;
            int ibuf;
            file >> buf;
            sku(buf);
            file >> buf;
            name(buf);
            file >> ibuf;
            quantity(ibuf);
            file >> ibuf;
            qtyNeeded(ibuf);
            file >> ibuf;
            taxed(ibuf != 0);
            file >> dbuf;
            price(dbuf);
            file.clear();
            file.close();
            return file;
        }
        virtual std::ostream& write(std::ostream& os, bool linear)const {
            return isEmpty() ? os : (os << sku() << ": " << name() << ", qty: "
                << quantity() << ", qtyNeeded:" << qtyNeeded()
                << ", Cost: " << fixed << setprecision(2) << cost());
        }
        virtual std::istream& read(std::istream& is) {
            char buf[2000];
            double dbuf;
            int ibuf;
            cout << "Sku: ";
            is >> buf;
            sku(buf);
            cout << "Name (no spaces): ";
            is >> buf;
            name(buf);
            cout << "Qty: ";
            is >> ibuf;
            quantity(ibuf);
            cout << "Qty Needed: ";
            is >> ibuf;
            qtyNeeded(ibuf);
            cout << "Is taxed? (1/0): ";
            is >> ibuf;
            taxed(ibuf != 0);
            cout << "Price: ";
            is >> dbuf;
            price(dbuf);
            return is;
        }
    };
}
void dumpFile(fstream& f) {
    f.open("ms4.txt", ios::in);
    char ch;
    while (!f.get(ch).fail()) {
        cout.put(ch);
    }
    f.clear();
    f.close();
}
using namespace sict;
void test() {
    double res, val = 0.0;
    fstream F("ms4.txt", ios::out);
    F.close();
    SItem S;
    SItem T;
    SItem U;
    cout << "Enter Product info: " << endl;
    cin >> S;
    SItem V = S;
    S.store(F);
    T.load(F);
    cout << "T: (store, load)" << endl;
    cout << T << endl;
    cout << "S: " << endl;
    cout << S << endl;
    cout << "V(S): " << endl;
    cout << V << endl;
    cout << "U=T & op= :" << endl;
    U = T;
    cout << U << endl;
    cout << "Operator == :" << endl;
    cout << "op== is " << (T == "1234" ? "OK" : "NOT OK") << endl;
    cout << "op+=: " << endl;
    U += 10;
    cout << U << endl;
    cout << "op+=double : " << endl;
    res = val += U;
    cout << res << "=" << val << endl;
}
int main() {
    fstream F("ms4.txt", ios::out);
    F.close();
    SItem S;
    SItem U("4321", "Rice");
    cout << "Empty Prouduct:" << endl << S << endl;
    cout << "U(\"4321\", \"Rice\"):" << endl << U << endl;

    cout << "Please enter the following information:" << endl;
    cout << "Sku: 1234" << endl;
    cout << "Name(no spaces) : Blanket" << endl;
    cout << "Qty : 12" << endl;
    cout << "Qty Needed : 23" << endl;
    cout << "Is taxed ? (1 / 0) : 1" << endl;
    cout << "Price : 12.34" << endl;
    test();
    cout << "Please enter the following information:" << endl;
    cout << "Sku: 1234" << endl;
    cout << "Name(no spaces) : Jacket" << endl;
    cout << "Qty : 12" << endl;
    cout << "Qty Needed : 23" << endl;
    cout << "Is taxed ? (1 / 0) : 0" << endl;
    cout << "Price : 12.34" << endl;
    test();
    dumpFile(F);
    cout << "----The End" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is my Product.h:

```
namespace sict {
    class Product : public Streamable {
        char sku_[MAX_SKU_LEN + 1];
        char * name_;
        double price_;
        bool taxed_;
        int quantity_;
        int qtyNeeded_;
    public:
        Product();
        Product(const char*, const char*, bool = true, double = 0, int = 0);
        Product(const Product&);
        virtual ~Product();
        Product& operator=(const Product&);
        //setters
        void sku(const char*);
        void price(double);
        void name(const char*);
        void taxed(bool);
        void quantity(int);
        void qtyNeeded(int);
        //getters
        const char* sku()const;
        double price()const;
        const char* name()const ;
        bool taxed()const;
        int quantity()const;
        int qtyNeeded()const;
        double cost()const;
        bool isEmpty()const;
        //member operators
        bool operator==(const char*);
        int operator+=(int);
        int operator-=(int);
    };

    double operator+=(double, const Product&);
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostr, const Product& p);
    std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& istr, Product& p);
}
```

All the functions have been implemented except the last two, which are the IO operators.

Streamable class is an abstract class that has no implementations.

Comment: what did you try and how does it fail? Btw there is lots of irrelevant code in your question. For streaming, it doesnt matter too much if the class has a `operator+=`...

Comment: The I/O operators are usually implemented as free functions, not as member functions.

Comment: As you see, the I/O operators are free functions

Comment: In the first sentence, you say 'non-member IO operator", yet it appears both of your un-implemented i/o op's are members?

Comment: They are not members. They are inside namespace, not class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did this wrong in many ways.
Best approach in your case is do it like that.

First define interfaces for stream operations, for your products:

```
class IStreamPrintable
{
public:
     virtual std::ostream& PrintToStream(std::ostream& outStream) const = 0;
};

class IStreamReadable
{
public:
     virtual std::istream& ReadFromStream(std::istream& inputStream) = 0;
};
```

Secondly define stream operators which will use this interfaces.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const IStreamPrintable& printObject)
{
    return printObject.PrintToStream(out);
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, IStreamReadable& readObject)
{
    return printObject.ReadFromStream(input);
}
```

Now you `Product` can inherit this interfaces:

```
class Product 
    : public IStreamPrintable
    , public IStreamReadable
{
   …
};
```

You do not have to implement it immediately. You can implement those methods in specific product classes `SItem` and it will work out of the box.

Your  method `virtual std::fstream& store(std::fstream& file, bool addNewLine = true)` is total mess. You are passing `fstream` object and opening some specific file on it. This is wrong since you are unable to write multiple objects to single file. Keep there `ostream` object and do not change is state (do only writing), so you could cascade calls and so you could avoid hard-coding a file name.

Comment: Should `readFromStream` be declared as a const method? My understanding of what you're trying to do with the function is directly update the class that it's reading into. Also in operator>> the object reference argument should not be const.

Comment: mistake made by copy paste :).

Comment: Just trying to keep everyone honest :)